# SQL query to add incrementing number for each group

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I would like to create a SQL query in automation studio that adds an incrementing number to all animals of the same type. This is my current data extension:

| UID | Animal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cow |
| 2 | Pig |
| 3 | Cow |
| 4 | Bird |
| 5 | Cat |

And the result should look like this:

| UID | Animal | TypeNr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cow | 1 |
| 2 | Pig | 2 |
| 3 | Cow | 1 |
| 4 | Bird | 3 |
| 5 | Cat | 4 |

I've found some solutions using "DENSE_RANK() over (order by Animal)" but since we can't use "oder by" in automation studio I have to look for an alternative solution. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a sidenote, ORDER BY is supported.

The key thing you might be looking for though is ROW_NUMBER().

Try this:

```
SELECT 
UID
,Animal
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Animal ORDER BY UID) AS TypeNr
FROM myDE
```

untested, but should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a seperate reference data extension where you assign a number to each animal like this:

| Animal | TypeNr |
| --- | --- |
| Cow | 1 |
| Pig | 2 |
| Bird | 3 |
| Cat | 4 |

And than you can write a join,

```
SELECT table1.UID, 
table1.animal, 
table2.TypeNr
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.animal = table2.animal
```